# Matrix product properties for isolation of a matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I think it should be pretty easy to have a reply to this question but I am not able to figure it out so far.

I have 2 rows:

(1) $a^TC \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$

(2) $a^TBC \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$

where

$a \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times1},B \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3},C \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$

EDIT : $B$ is a [skew-symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) (I don't know if it can help)

EDIT : $C$ is invertible

**I would like to express (2) as a *function* of (1)**

(Is there a way to isolate the term $a^TC$ or $(a^TC)^T$? )

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure that $a$ is a real number? If it is, doesn't make sense write $a^T$

Comment: I corrected immediately :) before looking at your comment. Thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean by 'isolate'? Do you mean to compute $a^T C$ give the value $a^T BC$?

Comment: I will edit my question and make it more clear. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Is $C$ invertible?

Comment: Yes, $C$ is invertible

Answer (score 0):

We could write
$$
a^TBC= (a^TC)(C^{-1}BC)
$$